# How to create primary key for a view in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Suppose I have two database `DB1`, and `DB2` both under the same instance. 
There is a table `tab2` in `DB2`. 
I created a view in `DB1` to get `tab2` from `DB2`:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Tab2]
AS
SELECT *
FROM  DB2.dbo.Tab2
```

Then I tried to create a key for `tab2` in `DB1`:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX tab2_Key
ON dbo. tab2 (id2)
```

This throws the following error:

> Msg 1939, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>  Cannot create index on view
>   'Tab2' because the view is not schema bound.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to accomplish, because when we tell you how to fix the error you're getting now, you're just going to step into a different error (I see at least two in your near future). Can you explain the goal instead of how you've decided to accomplish the goal?

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are several rules for a view having an index (some cascade from rules required for schemabinding).

One of the rules is that the view can't contain SELECT *. Another is that it has to exist in the same database as the object(s) it references.

I could list out the rules for you, but they are listed in the docs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx). And I don't think telling you the rules will accomplish much anyway.

Can you explain exactly what benefit you think a clustered index on this view would provide? Did someone tell you that an indexed view is "faster"? In this case I don't see what it will do for queries against `DB2.dbo.Tab2` especially if that table already has an index on `id2`. This just smells wrong in several ways...

Comment: I want to create an entity for tab2 in DB2 in a mode for DB1 with entity framework. Because if there is no key, EF can't create an entity for you in model. I don't care about performance for my case because I want this only for modeling. All data manipulation will be done by SP separately.

Comment: Sorry, you can't create an indexed view in another database, period. You will need to solve this another way, e.g. keeping a copy of the table up to date with triggers (or just point EF at the right table in the first place?).

Comment: thanks you. it is bad news for that. I will think another solution for this case.